# Simplification of the sum of 2 sequences multiplied

Tags: sequences-and-series

If it is possible, how can I simplify $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n b_n$, preferably into something in terms of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ given that $b_n$ = $100^n$

Comment: That does not seem possible.

Comment: I mean, how would you "simplify" $a_1b_1+a_2b_2$, which would be a far easier case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an upper bound, you might find the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality useful. For all $N$,

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}b_{n}\leq\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}b_{n}^{2}\right)^{1/2}.
$$

In particular, 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}b_{n}\leq\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}^{2}\right)^{1/2}.
$$

Since this holds for all $N$, it follows that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n}\leq\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}^{2}\right)^{1/2}.
$$